# Filter list of dictionariers and print value in Ansible/Jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I can't get my head around this, although it should be a trivial problem.

I'm using Ansible (and Jinja templating) to build a template and I have a list of dictionaries like (here displayed as JSON):

```
"datacenters": [{
    "description": "Main Datacenter", 
    "name": "main"
}, {
    "description": "Secondaty Datacenter", 
    "name": "secondary"
}]
```

And I want to filter by name an print the description. In my template I could get up to here:

```
{{ datacenters | selectattr("name", "equalto", "main") | list | first | to_nice_json }}
```

with output:

```
{
    "description": "Main Datacenter",
    "name": "main"           
}
```

But I can't get just `description`. For instance when I use:

```
{{ datacenters | selectattr("name", "equalto", "main") | list | first | attr("description") }}
```

I get:

```
AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'description'
```

I have found this link https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19356 googling the error, but I'm not loading the variable from the inventory.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group pipe's result:

```
{{ (datacenters | selectattr("name", "equalto", "main") | list | first).description }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it working, but using a workaround, so anyone who can provide a one-line solution is much more welcome.

Here is the workaround. In the template I used a set like:

```
{% set temp = datacenters | selectattr("name", "equalto", "main") | list | first %}
{{ temp["description"] }}
```

Which works, but I don't see why it shouldn't work in one line using `attr`